# Eliminating Stack Exchange inconsistency when using thousand separator?

Tags: feature-request, numbers

First, I appreciate Stack Exchange is using a thousand separator character at all. Not many sites and programs do.

Can Stack Exchange implement it more consistently?

Some examples where the separator is missing:

Tag question counts:

> [image]

Viewed counts:

> [image]

Comment: Hmm, dunno, but I think it would be more useful to explicitly request thousand separators for places you deem it's useful, not something as general as this.

Comment: @IͶΔ I disagree. This question asks for a decision of the team to add separators consistently. It is useless now to make an endless list of all the places it is missing.

Comment: Where is it used? I've never seen it in non-human-generated text

Comment: @cat http://i.stack.imgur.com/ubAlX.png (and more places where it's showing the full reputation)

Comment: Note that using a comma as a thousands separator is not an international standard; for instance here in AUS it is recommended to use a space rather than a comment.

Comment: Fine, but please use a thin space instead of a comma or period