# Thousands separators in reputation leagues

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues, numbers

I found today that reputation was difficult to read because there is no thousands separators for rank and rank change values in reputation leagues. (I saw this for [Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/).)

So for now it looks like this (anonymized :P)

> [image: Current screen]

"Total reputation" and "Year reputation" are easy to read, but there's neither comma nor right-aligned values for "Year rank" and "change" columns, so a little bit more difficult to read.

---

And With thousands separators, it may look like this:

> [image]

So I saw many other tickets about thousands separators, but no one talking about these year rank and rank change values.

Comment: Please introduce thousand separators **everywhere**.

Comment: [Eliminating Stack Exchange inconsistency when using thousand separator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277894/307988)

Comment: Please don't use `.` or `,` for thousand separators since they are used as decimal separators in other locales. A [thin space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space) would be great.